# C# - It's not possible to create an object with padding from the keyboard

Tags: c#

In the Main() method, implement the following algorithm programs:

- After starting the program from the keyboard, enter the number
  elements (for example, dogs), creates an array of objects of the class
  (for example, Dog), the size of the array corresponds to the number of these elements (for example, dogs).
- Several objects of the class (Dog class) are created in the loop depending on the number specified in the previous step, for each of these objects the name, breed, weight and age are set automatically on the keyboard (non-static method Next() of the Random class), these parameters are assigned to each
  object through the constructor.

Each newly created object must be stored in an array of objects.

I am new to programming, I will hope for help.
I got this code, I don't know how to create and populate objects:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Dog
    {
        private string name;     // кличка
        private string breed;    // порода
        private double weight;   // вага
        private int age;         // вік
        private char gender;     // стать
        
        public void Info()
        {
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            breed = Console.ReadLine();
            weight = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            gender = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            
            Console.WriteLine($"Кличка: {name} | Порода: {breed} | Вага: {weight} | Вік: {age} | Стать: {gender}");
        }
    }
    
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int dogsCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] dogs = new int[dogsCount];
            
            for(int i = 0; i < dogs.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Введіть елемент масиву під індексом {i}:\t");
                dogs[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            
            for(int i = 0; i < dogs.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dogs[i]);
            }
            
            //Dog dog = new Dog();
            //dog.Info();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Having `Dog.Info()` interact with the `Console` directly is not really the best way to populate its fields, but, still, how does the commented-out code at the end of `Main()` not accomplish your goal to "create and populate objects"?  If you change the fields of `Dog` from `private` to `public` or `internal` you'll be able to access them from the `Program` class.

Comment: When you do "private string name;", you just created and object of the type "string", with the name "name", so how can you ask "I don't know how to create and populate objects"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define constructor which save input properties to new dog object. Method GetInfo returns string with complete info about dog.

After start you have to ask to dog count and then in for loop you have to read individual properties for each dog. These properties you should send to the constructor of the dog object. Then you can save new dog to array and show info about dog.

```
using System;

public class Dog
{
    private string Name { get; set; }
    private string Breed { get; set; }
    private double Weight { get; set; }
    private int Age { get; set; }
    private char Gender { get; set; }
    
    public Dog(string name, string breed, double weight, int age, char gender)
    {
        Name = name;
        Breed = breed;
        Weight = weight;
        Age = age;
        Gender = gender;
    }
    
    public string GetInfo()
    {
        return string.Format("Name: {0} | Breed: {1} | Weight: {2} | Age: {3} | Gender: {4}", Name, Breed, Weight, Age, Gender);
    }
}
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many dogs?");
        int dogsCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        
        Dog[] dogs = new Dog[dogsCount];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < dogsCount; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("==================================");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Creating dog {0}/{1}", i + 1, dogsCount));
            
            Console.WriteLine("Name:");
            var name = Console.ReadLine();
            
            Console.WriteLine("Breed:");
            var breed = Console.ReadLine();
            
            Console.WriteLine("Weight:");
            var weight = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            
            Console.WriteLine("Age:");
            var age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            
            Console.WriteLine("Gender:");
            var gender = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            
            var dog = new Dog(name, breed, weight, age, gender);
            dogs[i] = dog;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Created dog -> {0}", dog.GetInfo()));
        }
    }
}
```